# Possible ground state wavefunctions of anti-ferromagnetic Heisenberg spin chains

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, lattice-model

1. What are the ground state wavefunctions of the anti-ferromagnetic (AFM) Heisenberg spin chains?

Is that which of the following?
$$| ↑↓↑↓ · · · ↑↓>$$
or 
$$| ↓↑↓↑ . . . ↓↑>$$
or
$$| ↑↓↑↓ · · · ↑↓> +| ↓↑↓↑ . . . ↓↑>$$
or
$$| ↑↓↑↓ · · · ↑↓> - | ↓↑↓↑ . . . ↓↑>$$

2. What are the number of ground states?
3. What are the Neel states?

Comment: Which spin - spin 1/2, spin 1, ... ?

Comment: @Nobert Both cases, spin 1/2 and spin 1

Comment: You *are* aware that the physics of integer and half-integer Heisenberg chains is fundamentally different?

Comment: Yes. Spin-1/2: One is gapless like O(3) NLSM. Spin-1: The other is gapped, either trivial or Haldane phase.

Comment: Wonder how to view the wavefunction.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch I post a new question maybe you also know it -- a lattice model